# Django cycling templates

Tags: django, templates, include, cycle

I need to output objects in Django template, so that each object has its own template. Templates are keeped in the variable "templates" like that - ['path/to/template1','path/to/template2', ...]

Is there a way to "cycle" these templates in object loop, somehow like that:

```
{% for object in objects %}
   {% cycle templates as template %}
   {% include template %} // this code is just for example
{% endfor %}
```

I cannot include these templates directly into objects list, because it is generated by paginator's template tag.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written the template tag that receives a list variable and cycles it through the loop.

```
from django import template
from django.template.base import TemplateSyntaxError, Node

from itertools import cycle as itertools_cycle

register = template.Library()

class CycleListNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, list_variable, template_variable):
        self.list_variable = list_variable
        self.template_variable = template_variable

    def render(self, context):
        if self not in context.render_context:
            # First time the node is rendered in template
            context.render_context[self] = itertools_cycle(context[self.list_variable])
        cycle_iter = context.render_context[self]
        value = cycle_iter.next()
        if self.template_variable:
            context[self.template_variable] = value
        return ''

@register.tag
def cycle_list(parser, token):
    args = token.split_contents()
    if len(args) != 4 or args[-2] != 'as':
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(u"Cycle_list tag should be in the format {% cycle_list list as variable %}")
    return CycleListNode(args[1], args[3])
```

It's pretty simple but solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a template tag that does what you want with the templates, and it should take a path ( template's path ) as an argument, then all you would need to do is pass the path template path variable which should be in the context if you are using request context to your custom template tag, like so

```
{% custom_tag path_to_template_dir %}
```